# How do I install an older version of the php5-mhash package?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 10.04, php

I have my PHP Version pinned at 5.2.x, Here is the command line output

```
php -version
PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2009 16:30:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

Running this command to install [php5-mhash](http://packages.ubuntu.com/php5-mhash):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mhash
```

Here is the error message

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   php5-mhash: Depends:
php5-common (= 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.10) but 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6
is to be installed E: Broken packages
```

My question is how do I fix this? Can I install an older version of `php5-mhash` and if so, how do I do that?

Here is the output from running: `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -a`, then running `sudo apt-get install php5-mhash`.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -a
E: Command line option 'a' [from -a] is not known.

Comment: Did you mean sudo apt-get install -f ?, added output to question

Comment: Oups, yes... Gah. Sorry.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Mixing packages from different releases can cause all the sort of problems, you should keep with your target release packages.

Comment: The pinned version is so I don't upgrade past production server versions as 5.2 and 5.3 are very different. I also need to run several projects locally on my machine which will cause problems if I upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if anyone is facing this problem I figured it out.

Download and install it manually

Here are the steps:

(I'm using the Karmic Repo to match the version I have pinned)

[Download the matching version from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/php5-mhash). Installed on my box is this version `php-common 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6` So [this is the version I downloaded](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/php5-mhash/5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6)

Then I manually installed the package like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i php5-mhash_5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

Output:

```
Selecting previously deselected package php5-mhash. (Reading database
... 357032 files and directories currently installed.) Unpacking
php5-mhash (from php5-mhash_5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6_i386.deb) ...
Setting up php5-mhash (5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6) ...
```

**Note:** I did install the wrong version before finding the correct version to download and install. The output was something like this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i php5-mhash_5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4_i386.deb  
Selecting previously deselected package php5-mhash.
(Reading database ... 357032 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking php5-mhash (from php5-mhash_5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-mhash:
  php5-mhash depends on php5-common (= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4); however:
    Version of php5-common on system is 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.
dpkg: error processing php5-mhash (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:  php5-mhash
```

Running this to fix the broken install:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:
  libmhash2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php5-mhash
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 69.6kB disk space will be freed. Do you
want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 357033 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-mhash
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini` and also `/usr/lib/php5`.

Comment: Can you please explain why this will fix it?